# Joining pandas dataframes based on minimization of distance

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset of stores with 2D locations at daily timestamps. I am trying to match up each row with weather measurements made at stations at some other locations, also with daily timestamps, such that the Cartesian distance between each store and matched station is minimized. The weather measurements have not been performed daily, and the station positions may vary, so this is a matter of finding the closest station for each specific store at each specific day.

I realize that I can construct nested loops to perform the matching, but I am wondering if anyone here can think of some neat way of using pandas dataframe operations to accomplish this. A toy example dataset is shown below. For simplicity, it has static weather station positions.

```
store_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'store_id': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
    'x': [1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
    'y': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4],
    'date': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]})

weather_station_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'station_id': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
    'weather': [20, 21, 19, 17, 16, 18, 19, 17],
    'x': [0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 3, 3, 3],
    'y': [2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3],
    'date': [1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3]})
```

The data below is the desired outcome. I have included `station_id` only for clarification.

```
   store_id  date  station_id  weather
0         1     1           1       20
1         1     2           1       21
2         1     3           1       19
3         2     1           2       17
4         2     2           3       19
5         2     3           2       16
6         3     1           3       18
7         3     2           3       19
8         3     3           3       17
```

Comment: So an exact match on date, and then which store is the closest in distance? Or is date irrelevant?

Comment: Jupp, exact match on date, closest match on position is what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea of the solution is to build the table of all combinations,

```
df = store_df.merge(weather_station_df, on='date', suffixes=('_store', '_station'))
```

calculate the distance

```
df['dist'] = (df.x_store - df.x_station)**2 + (df.y_store - df.y_station)**2
```

and choose the minimum per group:

```
df.groupby(['store_id', 'date']).apply(lambda x: x.loc[x.dist.idxmin(), ['station_id', 'weather']]).reset_index()
```

If you have a lot of date the you can do the join per group.

Comment: Thanks. Very neat solution that works reasonably efficiently for my dataset of 200+ stores and 200+ weather stations with daily timestamps for a year. I have accepted your answer, because it was the one I ended up using, although it is very similar to the answer posted by @kudeh. When making the final product with several years of data, I will write up something similar in Spark.

Answer (score 2):

```
import math
import numpy as np

def distance(x1, x2, y1, y2):
    return np.sqrt((x2-x1)**2 + (y2-y1)**2)

#Join On Date to get all combinations of store and stations per day
df_all = store_df.merge(weather_station_df, on=['date'])

#Apply distance formula to each combination
df_all['distances'] = distance(df_all['x_y'], df_all['x_x'], df_all['y_y'], df_all['y_x'])

#Get Minimum distance for each day Per store_id
df_mins = df_all.groupby(['date', 'store_id'])['distances'].min().reset_index()

#Use resulting minimums to get the station_id matching the min distances
closest_stations_df = df_mins.merge(df_all, on=['date', 'store_id', 'distances'], how='left')

#filter out the unnecessary columns
result_df = closest_stations_df[['store_id', 'date', 'station_id', 'weather', 'distances']].sort_values(['store_id', 'date'])
```

edited: To use vectorized distance formula

Comment: Thanks, this is great. I ended up using and therefore accepting the code by @JoergVanAken, which is slightly neater. If I could have accepted two answers I would have in this case.